# How to read utc timestamps from Sql Server using RODBC in R?

Tags: sql-server, r, timezone, utc, rodbc

I am trying to import some data from Sql Server 2008 into R, using RODBC with:

```
db <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=server; Database=db;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
results <- sqlQuery(db, "select timestamp from table where some-restriction")
```

The data is stored in a column of type "datetime". All timestamps are in UTC, however my system timezone is CET. R converts all timestamps to values of type "POSIXct" "POSIXt" e.g:

"2011-01-01 07:24:12 CET"

"2011-01-01 08:35:10 CET"

"2011-01-01 09:02:50 CET"

timestamps are correct, timezone is wrong. Is seems to me that since timezone is not explicitly specified, R assigns to all timestamps my local timezone.

Is there any way the timezone of the data can be specified, so timezone information would be correct?

Comment: I don't have RODBC and a db to connect to, but have you tried `Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")` before querying the db?

Comment: Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC') will indeed work. Are there any other options which do not effect the entire system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre R 3.1.0, and when this answer was originally written:

For objects of class `POSIXlt`, you could modify the `tzone` attribute of the variable directly after importing the data:

```
attr(results$timestamp,"tzone") <- "UTC"
```

If your data is of class `POSIXct` this will change the data by the timezone offset, so convert to `POSIXlt` first by wrapping in an `as.POSIXlt()`:

```
results$timestamp <- as.POSIXlt(results$timestamp)
```

eg:

```
tm <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
tm
[1] "2011-09-20 13:45:01 BST"
attr(tm,"tzone") <- "UTC"
tm
[1] "2011-09-20 13:45:01 UTC"
```

Since R 3.1.0 this behaviour has changed to use a component of the POSIXlt object rather than an attribute, and is obliquely referenced in the news by:

> Printing of date-times will make use of the time-zone abbreviation in
>   use at the time, if known. For example, for Paris pre-1940 this could
>   be LMT, PMT, WET or WEST. To enable this, the "POSIXlt" class has an
>   optional component "zone" recording the abbreviation for each element.

So now you would just use `tm$zone <- "UTC"`

Comment: This converts the time to UTC, so it changes the actual hour by the zone offset.

Comment: I can confirm that your example works indeed, I have no idea why it does not work with values from db, maybe it has something to do that the tzone information is missing.

Comment: attr(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()),"tzone") prints "CET" "CET" "CEST" when used on value from database attr(dbvalue,"tzone") it prints ""

Comment: @GregorS. I think it will do that with objects of class `POSIXct`, which doesn't have a `tzone` attribute by default.

Comment: You are correct, if the values are first converted to POSIXlt with as.POSIXlt(dbvalues), your solution will work to, can you edit the answer?

Comment: @GregorS. OK, will do, but it does say that the values are `POSIXlt` in the question

Comment: The exact same code as you posted doesn't work for me.  I still get my local time zone instead of UTC on last line.  Maybe something changed in 6 years.

Comment: @EricP It changed from R 3.1.0, I've edited the answer to provide the new way of doing it.

Answer (score 6):

Probably easiest to change the timezone afterwards.

```
library(lubridate)
tz(results) <- "UTC"
```

Comment: I accepted @James answer since it does not use additional libraries.